# Airplane mode verification No class Def

Tags: android

This code generates the following error. Does anyone know why? Thanks!

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.provider.Settings$Global`

```
@SuppressLint( "NewApi" )
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
           Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0; //<--Error here
    } else {
        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
               Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check following:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
```

Because the class was introduced in API level 17 that is Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1. Alternatively you could do:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
```